# Jabber/XMPP gem for Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, xmpp, instant-messaging

Im looking for a solid and working XMPP gem for rails 3.2

There are hundreds of them in the net, but most of them outdated or alpha.

Can you recommend me one for rails 3.2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gem xmpp4r works fine. (https://github.com/ln/xmpp4r)

Here is an example:

```
require 'xmpp4r'

sender_jid = Jabber::JID.new('a@b.com')
client = Jabber::Client.new(sender_jid)
client.connect('talk.google.com')
client.auth('password')

client.send(Jabber::Presence.new.set_show(:chat)).set_status('my status')

receiver_jid = Jabber::JID.new("dest@domain.com")
message = Jabber::Message::new(receiver_jid, "Testing").set_type(:normal).set_id('1')
client.send(message)
```

Comment: hey this is work for me , thanx but can you tell me How to recieve and remove message?

Comment: I think they have explained pretty well in this https://www.sitepoint.com/looking-xmpp-xmpp4r-gem/