# How to send XMPP message from Rails Web to Mobile App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, ruby-on-rails-4, xmpp, xmpp4r

We need to build a mobile application whose API will be written in Ruby on Rails. There is a requirement to send xmpp messages for some cases to mobile ? Please help how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with [the ruby toolbox](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com)? It is a database of all available rubygems that you can search from. You can search for xmpp and it'll give you a lot of gems that might fit your needs.

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=xmpp

[Blather](https://github.com/adhearsion/blather) or [Xmpp4r](https://github.com/xmpp4r/xmpp4r) sound like good candidates.

Check out these other related SO questions:

- [What do I need for integrating XMPP into Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326439/what-do-i-need-for-integrating-xmpp-into-rails)
- [Jabber/XMPP gem for Rails 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018444/jabber-xmpp-gem-for-rails-3-2)
- [Android and XMPP: Currently available solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions)
- [What is XMPP, and how can I use it within an iOS chat application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495204/what-is-xmpp-and-how-can-i-use-it-within-an-ios-chat-application)

Comment: I saw XMPP4r gem.. but couldn't find how to add mobile to send xmpp message in it.

Comment: You probably need to read more about the protocol http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/ and try to interact with it with a very basic program before you jump into implementing it in production. You'll need an xmpp server such as http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/ and some client libraries to interact with it both on the rails side and on the mobile side. That's what my answer is about.

Comment: Is there are any other options to XMPP4r gem because still I don't see any updated gem for XMPP.

Comment: Blather seems to still be maintained. Last commits in January. https://github.com/adhearsion/blather